# Evolución del adjetivo "actual"

Tags: significado, historia, adjetivos

Actualmente usamos la palabras "actual" para referirnos al tiempo presente, como se recoge en el diccionario:

> **[actual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cuhZiL)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. actuālis.
> ```
>
> 1. adj. Dicho del tiempo en que se está: **presente**.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al tiempo actual. *Civilizaciones actuales. Cine actual.*

Normalmente se considera esta palabra un falso amigo del inglés *actual*, que significa "algo que existe en la realidad" pero no tiene por qué limitarse al presente. De ahí que traduzcamos "la hora actual" como "the current time" y, al revés, "the actual costs" como "los costes reales".

Sin embargo, parece que esto no siempre fue así. Buscando en diccionarios antiguos me encuentro con esta definición en el primer tomo del *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1726):

> ACTUAL. Lo que real y verdaderamente existe al tiempo que se dice, ò enuncia.

Esta defninición me resulta, de hecho, más parecida a la actual definición inglesa que a la española. Y si no, véanse estos dos ejemplos que cita:

> La segunda cosa que se requiere es *actuál* devolución.
>   Aunque es verdád que vos *actualmente* no haveis hecho ofensa en esta casa.

El primer ejemplo ni siquiera habla del presente, sino de algo hipotético que puede ocurrir en el futuro, y de hecho veo ese ejemplo un uso perfecto del *actual* inglés, no del español. Hoy día hablaríamos de "se requiere devolución real". El segundo ejemplo me parece más confuso, puesto que se podría entender como "hasta hoy no habéis hecho ofensa" o como "en realidad no habéis hecho ofensa", me faltaría algo más de contexto.

En todo caso, diría que en el siglo XVIII el uso de *actual* en español era idéntico al *actual* del inglés actual. ¿Es así? Y si es así, ¿cómo ha evolucionado la palabra? ¿Cuándo comenzó a usarse con el sentido actual?

---

A continuación el caso más antiguo encontrado en el CORDE, usado en una frase en pasado, lo que descarta el uso como "que sucede en el presente":

> *Otrossí, que se deve confessar todo commo del pecado actual que fizo, siquier sea omne, siquier muger, siquier rico, quier pobre [...].*
>
> Pedro de Cuéllar, "Catecismo", 1325 (España).

Entiendo la frase como que se deben confesar los pecados reales (tal cual sucedieron o tuvieron lugar, es decir, tal y como fue el *acto*).

Comment: A priori está claro que *actual* se veía antes como el antónimo de *potencial* o *hipotético*, siguiendo el contraste filosófico en potencia y acto (ver [acto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cnCBhK) en el DLE, def. 9). Pero no podría decir cuándo y cómo fue evolucionando.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que el cambio se produjo en el mismo s XVIII y siguientes, en dos etapas: 1770-1869 y 1884-actualidad.
En  el Diccionario de Autoridades (1726) se define

- ACTUAL. adj. de una term. Lo que real y verdaderamente [i.72] existe al tiempo que se dice, ò enúncia. Viene del Latino Actualis, que significa esto mismo.
- ACTUALMENTE. adv. de modo. Real y verdaderamente, con actuál ser, y exercício

En la siguiente edición, de **1770** se definen como [énfasis mio]:

- ACTUAL: adj. de una term. Lo mismo que existente o **presente**.
- ACTUALMENTE: **ahora, al presente**

Estas definiciones se conservan sin modificaciones hasta la edición de **1869** inclusive.

Y en la edición de **1884** se avanza hasta unas definiciones muy parecidas a las de hoy dia [énfasis mio]:

- ACTUAL: **Presente**, 2ª acepc. (*) || **Que existe, sucede o se usa en el tiempo presente.** || Activo, que obra.
- ACTUALMENTE: **En el tiempo presente.**

(*) La segunda acepción de "presente" citada es: "Dicese del tiempo en que actualmente esta uno cuando refiere una cosa".

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Spanish.SE! Aportas muy buenas contribuciones, pero sigues siempre apareciendo como "nuevo usuario" porque nunca te registras. Estás completamente en tu derecho, pero, ¿alguna razón en particular?

Comment: @wimi: No he podido responder en META a tu último post, por lo que aprovecho la ocasión para comentartelo aquí: Me parece fantástico y valiente que te hayas presentado (y sido nombrado) moderador y te doy las gracias y felicitaciones por ello. ¡Mucha suerte, paciencia y ánimo! En cuanto a tu pregunta concreta, la razón para no registrarme es que no me gusta la "gamificación" del sistema y que haya que obtener puntos para hacer determinadas cosas (comentarios, participar en chats, etc.). Por lo que pregunto y respondo  sin registrarme, tal y como llevo tiempo haciéndo con distintos nombres.

Comment: tu decisión :) si en algún momento decides que quieres privilegios, seguro que no te costará nada conseguirlos. Si no, gracias por las buenas, y desinteresadas, contribuciones al sitio, y gracias por las felicitaciones también!

Comment: Your decision not to register means extra work for people who monitor the review queues so although I understand your point about the silly system it is not without a small cost to others.

Comment: "Silly" system? The user didn't say so...